# sql developer "%s: invalid identifier", error on foreign key

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm creating two tables, the primary key of `manager` is the foreign key of `employees`, but I'm getting this error:

> Error report -
>   SQL Error: ORA-00904: "MANAGER_ID": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier".

```
create table managers(
  manager_id number(9),
  manager_name varchar(50),
  primary key(manager_id)
);
create table employees
(
  emp_id number(9),
  emp_name varchar(50) not null,
  primary key(emp_id),
  foreign key(manager_id) references managers(manager_id)
);
```

Please help, thanks a lot.

Comment: There is no column `manager_id` in the table `employees`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean?

```
create table managers(
  manager_id number(9),
  manager_name varchar(50),
  primary key(manager_id)
);
create table employees
(
  emp_id number(9),
  manager_id number(9),
  emp_name varchar(50) not null,
  primary key(emp_id),
  foreign key(manager_id) references managers(manager_id)
);
```

because there is no manager_id in in employees table in your SQL statement.